# Razor Core 2 Output variable inside html tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-2.1

I cannot seem to output a var inside the  tag.  I used to do it like the code below in MVC2 razor.  But now it looks like the  tag looks like some kind of reserved tag.

```
<select class="form-control" id="CompanyId" name="CompanyId">
    @{ 
        foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
        {
            var selected = "";

            if (item.CompanyId == Model.CompanyId)
            {
                selected = "selected";
            }

            <option value="@item.CompanyId" @selected>@item.Name</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach like below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="CompanyId" name="CompanyId">
    @{ 
        foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
        {
            if (item.CompanyId == Model.CompanyId)
            {
                <option value="@item.CompanyId" selected>@item.Name</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@item.CompanyId">@item.Name</option>
            }
        }
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't correct way to write razor, you treat it like a HTML text. Use boolean inside the attribute and it will nicely use the attribute when it evaluates true and won't render attribute at all if false (or null).

```
<select class="form-control" id="CompanyId" name="CompanyId">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
    {
        <option value="@item.CompanyId" selected="@(item.CompanyId == Model.CompanyId)">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

---

But you should use tag helpers and model binding instead, this will make your code much easier to maintain.

**View**

```
@model HomeViewModel

<select class="form-control" asp-for="CompanyId" asp-items="Model.Companies"></select>
```

**Model** *(assuming select options are static, otherwise populate inside controller)*

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public readonly List<SelectListItem> Companies = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem("Microsoft", "Microsoft"),
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Yahoo", Text = "Yahoo" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Google", Text = "Google", Disabled = true, Selected = false }
    };
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel
    {
        CompanyId = "Yahoo"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```